# Why do I have 19.5A on one leg of utility feed and 0A on the other with no load?

Tags: wiring

We have been experience high winds and rain lately. I noticed my fan on the wood burner changing speeds when TV is turned on and off. Did some reading on here and put a amp clamp on my earth ground reads zero.

Put amp clamp on power company feeder wires on my side of the meter and with no load I get 19.5 amps on one leg and 0 on the other.

This can't be right can it?

Comment: Voltage reading from both legs to neutral will help.  Having 0 amps on one leg is just the power you are using, might not be using any power from that leg or that leg is dead.  Is this North America?  Might have a bad neutral or hot feed from the pole,power company's problem.

Comment: 122.7 volts and 123.0 volts

Comment: I missed the 19.5 amps with "no load".

Comment: show us a picture of where and how you are clamping for the current measurement

Comment: You say 0 amps on "earth ground" but did you measure current on neutral?  If there is 19A on one leg, there must be 19A somewhere else.  Hopefully the neutral.  While measuring the leg with the 19A, try turning breakers off to see which one is responsible.  "No load" really means you don't know where the load is :)

Comment: Power comes into a 100 amp breaker. The only other breaker in the box is a 50 amp breaker that feeds a subpanel with multiple breakers. When I check each leg to neutral in the subpanel they read 120.3 volts and 126 v. I tightened all the grounds and neutrals in the main panel and subpanel which did not change results.

Comment: No camera on phone due to left phone on top of truck tire syndrome.

Comment: what voltage do you measure between the two legs?

Comment: There are other ways of taking pictures...

Answer (score 5):

Sounds super normal to me.  Each 120V load in your house is placed on

- a randomly picked phase aka pole
- neutral

And if all your active loads *happen to be* on one phase/pole, well, that's what that will look like.    It's hardly of concern.

If you are saying 19.5A yet all your loads are off, that is not true.  You missed one.

If all this is news to you, [here's a primer on how 120/240V split-phase works](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jMmUoZh3Hq4) that pokes some fun at Europeans (hey, turnabout is fair play lol).

### However, it could be a lost phase.

Given that you just had a storm, it's possible you lost a phase/pole. Now you'd expect half your circuits to lose power, *but no!* Most houses have 240V loads which connect between the two phases/poles.  When they switch on, they become a resistor connecting the dead phase to the live phase.

So the dead phase will come back "weakly" - voltage will sag somewhat, about 10 volts per amp drawn.  *But that only applies if loads are switched on, and you say they are not*.  But it can work well enough for smaller loads to "fool you" into thinking the phase isn't dead.

Your reading of 20A on L1 / 0A on L2 sounds like a disconnected L2.

It's very common for consumers to report "many of my outlets and lights are dead, but they come back on when I turn on my oven, even though the oven doesn't heat up".  That is exactly that symptom.

The water heater is a real wild card. It switches on when the thermostat tells it to. So the "half the circuits coming back" thing may happen randomly and seem like "gremlins".

### How do you test for a Lost Phase/pole

Shut off every one of your 240V loads.  Now go see if half your circuits are stone dead.  If they are, and turning on a 240V load like the oven or dryer "semi-fixes it", then you have a lost phase.

What do you do?  Call the power company **and report an outage**.  Do it now.  They will come out immediately and fix it.

Keep it simple. Switch off your 240V loads, note that half your circuits are dead, *and report exactly that and nothing else*.  Otherwise they may give you the runaround, and try to convince you it's a problem with house wiring.